# How to compile angular expression {{scope.somevalue}} in ng-bind-html in DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am having some controller contains the $scope values which is html string and a variable

```
$scope.variableText="value of variable";
$scope.htmlString = "<b>HP LaserJet 1020</b> printer provides ________________ dpi printing. {{variableText}}";
```

and in view DOM element I have used

```
<span><ANY ng-bind-html="htmlString | unsafe"></ANY></span>
```

for trust as html i have use this filter function,

```
app.filter('unsafe',function($sce) 
{
     return $sce.trustAsHtml; 
});
```

it successfully gives result as HTML output but it won't parse the {{variableText}}

**HP LaserJet 1020** printer provides ________________ dpi printing. {{variableText}}

Comment: You have to compile it with the scope that the value is attached to. Look at [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

### HTML

```
<span><ANY ng-bind-html="htmlString | unsafe:this"></ANY></span>
```

### JS

```
app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', '$compile', function ($sce, $compile) {
return function (input, scope) {

    //create an angular element. (this is still our "view")
    var el = angular.element(input);

    //compile the view into a function.
    var compiled = $compile(el);

    //bind our view to the scope!
    //(try commenting out this line to see what happens!)
    compiled(scope);

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(el);
};}]);
```

Comment: I am not sure that this will work if you write a fiddle i can test that. Thanks.